# Mock a dependency within a service

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

I am attempting to mock a dependency within a service. I have no idea what is going wrong.. its not exact a great class to test but its all about code coverage - here is the service

```
@Injectable()
export class SessionService {
    constructor(private sessionStore: UserStore){}

    login(userData: User) {
        this.sessionStore.login(userData);
    }
    logout(){
        this.sessionStore.logout();
    }
}
```

the dependancy UserStore looks like this:

```
export function createInitialState(): User {
    return {
        id: 0, password: "", role: undefined, username: "",
    }
}
@Injectable()
@StoreConfig({ name: 'session', resettable: true })
export class UserStore extends Store<User> {
    constructor() {
        super(createInitialState());
    }

    login(user: User){
        this.update(user);
    }

    logout(){
        this.reset();
        this.update(createInitialState());
    }

    getCurrentUser(){
        return this.getValue();
    }
}
```

the unit test:

```
describe('SessionService', () => {
   // @ts-ignore
   let sessionService: SessionService;
   let userStoreMock;
   beforeEach(() => {

       userStoreMock = {
           login: jest.fn(),
           logout: jest.fn()
       };

       TestBed.configureTestingModule({
           providers:[{ provide: UserStore, useValue: userStoreMock}]
       });

       sessionService = TestBed.get(SessionService);
   });

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(sessionService).toBeDefined();
    })
});
```

the error i get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getComponentFromError' of null
```

Comment: you didn't provide SessionService to the TestBed ? but trying to get from TestBed sessionService = TestBed.get(SessionService);

Comment: @Ininiv i still get the same error passing it in

Answer (score 1):

In order to mock a service you should create a spy object (jasmine.createSpyObj) from the methods you want to use and then mock the return value from those methods.

For example:

```
let mockService;

mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['methodOne', 'methodTwo']);
mockService.methodOne.and.returnValue(of(MOCKED_DATA_1));
mockService.methodTwo.and.returnValue(of(MOCKED_DATA_2));
```

and then you set that mockService inside your configureTestingModule's providers:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   ...
   providers: [
       ...
       {
           provide: MyService, useValue: mockService
       }
   ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`SessionService` is not added to the providers list.

The configuration should be

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers:[
        SessionService,
        { provide: UserStore, useValue: userStoreMock}
    ]
});
```

After this, if you get the same issue, then add the below code inside `beforeEach()`.

```
TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
 TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

Test.ts

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

Comment: I get Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?). as an error after doing all of that.

Comment: May be there is some issue with test.ts.